# Specify the loading sequence of the scripts in a Composer Business Network

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-composer

Can I specify the sequence of the scripts that have dependency relationship? I construct the following example to illustrate my question.

lib/script0.js:

```
Settings = {
  hello: "hello 2 "
}
```

lib/script1.js:

```
helloText = Settings.hello
```

I tested the example above in the composer playground. With the default sequence, script1.js was loaded before script0.js and caused " ReferenceError: Settings is not defined". Can I specify the sequence of the scripts that are loaded into transaction Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no support for controlling the load order of scripts. I would advise against using global objects in your scripts (because the context may be recycled).

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We wanted to include some third party lib that export itself as a global variable. We ended up moving all the references to the global variables to a function called during transaction. As every time the whole script will be rerun, global object will recreate every time so there will not be recycling problem.